# Scheduling App/Commands in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, cron, queue, laravel-5

Here is the `SendBirthdayEmailCommand` command created under `/App/Commands/` directory

```
class SendBirthdayEmailCommand extends Command implements ShouldBeQueued {

    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}
```

with a `handler` class `SendBirthdayEmailCommandHandler` in `/App/Handlers/` diretory

```
class SendBirthdayEmailCommandHandler {

public function __construct()
{
    //
}


public function handle(SendBirthdayEmailCommand $command)
{
    //
        $reminders = \App\Reminder::all()->where('reminder_status','=','scheduled')
                     ->where('reminder_set','=','birthday')
                     ->where('reminder_type','=','email')
                     ->where('reminder_time','<=',  \Carbon\Carbon::now('Asia/Kolkata'));

       foreach ($reminders as $reminder) {
           $this->sendEmailNow($reminder);
       }
}

public function sendEmailNow($reminder_record)
{
    $reminderdata = $reminder_record;
    $from = $reminderdata->reminder_from;
    $to = $reminderdata->reminder_to;
    $msgstring = $reminderdata->reminder_msg;

   \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::queueOn(
                'birthday_email', 
                ['html' => 'emails.bdaymailhtml'], 
                $msgstring, 
                function($message){
                  $message->from('reminder@example.com', 'Reeminder');
                  $message->to($to,'')->subject('Happy Birthday to You!');
                }

   );
 }
}
```

How to `Dispatch` this `Command` Every 1 Hour from the schedular

[Laravel doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan#scheduling-artisan-commands) only shows example of scheduling console commands, not Commands under `App/Commands` diretory

**Edit 1**

To be more specific, I would like to dispatch the `SendBirthdayEmailCommand` from the Schedular
Is that a correct approach? Or do i have to create a console command explicitly and then make a call to my command in `App/Commands`

P.S. The two command references are confusing. `commands` in `/App/Console/Commands` are the `artisan console commands` then what we call the `commands` in `/App/Commands` directory with their `handler` classes in `/App/Handlers` Directory

**Edit 2**

As suggested by @luceos here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31043897/1679510

I have used closure as below to dispatch the `SendBirthdayEmailCommand` from `/app/Console/Kernel.php`

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('inspire')
             ->hourly();
           $schedule->call(function()
            {
                $this->dispatch(new App\Commands\SendBirthdayEmailCommand());

            })->hourly();
}
```

And to avail the `dispatch()` method in Kernel I have also did following

1. Availing `Command Bus Facade` to `Kernel`

   ```
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesCommands;
   ```
2. Using the Facade inside `Kernel` class

   ```
   class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {

   use DispatchesCommands;
   /* rest of the code */
   }
   ```

   Let's see if that works!! Figuring out how to run cron on xampp to let the schedular run.

Also unsure, where would i get the debug log if there comes any error

**Update:**

After a bit playing with the Kernel and then running `php artisan` Have found that `only console commands can be registered in kernel`

For Example

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {

protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\Inspire',
    '\App\Commands\SendBirthdayEmailCommand', /* This will give error */
];
}
```

The Commands under `app/Commands/` directory cannot be registered in kernel, as it only accepts `instance of console commands`

So that said, If we would like to call `app/commands/MyCommand` command in `schedule` method with something like `$schedule->command('mycmd')`  **Do we have to create an explicit console command?**

Comment: please add the code inline

Comment: @Luceos thanks added !! Also the command in turn is creating queued jobs that need to be processed with queue:listener or similar

Answer (score 1):

You would edit the `app/Console/Kernel.php` class and add your command under `schedule()` method using:

```
$schedule->command('birthday-email')->everyHour();
```

Assuming you named your `App\Commands\SendBirthdayEmailCommand` `birthday-email` using property `$name`.

As you have two classes I think you mixed things up. You would need to move the `handle()` method of `SendBirthdayEmailCommandHandler` to the `SendBirthdayEmailCommand` or call the method from within the command.

If you want to call arbitrary things you can also simply use the call method:

```
schedule->call(function()
{
    // Do some task...

})->hourly();
```

Comment: and that's so straight .. I thought only console commands can be scheduled. Let me try that

Comment: but the Handler works in the same way (without calling it explicitly) right? you define the Command and then you define the handler and you actully dispatch that command from command bus 
I just want this dispatching code to be under the schedule method so that it dispatch that every hour .. is that a correct approach??

Comment: see the addition, you can also use closures to be scheduled.

Comment: In commands by default the handle method is called yes. Just take a look at `app/Console/Commands/Inspire.php`

Comment: sorry for confusions, I'm addressing App/Commands 
So when i dispatch it from controller like this `$this->dispatch(new \App\Commands\SendBirthdayEmailCommand ());` handler is processed automatically
Similarly can i dispatch the same from the schedular without explicitly creating console commans ?

Comment: Dispatch puts something on the queue, schedule runs something periodically, these are different things. You could use `call()` to instantiate your handler object and do the magic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81499/discussion-between-echoashu-and-luceos).

Comment: No Probs, I'll happily await ur thoughts on the my question when u r free :-)

Comment: I'm unsure what your follow up question is. If the answer is incomplete or you haven't been able to make your code now work, please let me know.

Comment: The only question, can i use Command Bus Dispatch method inside the schedule function ?? 
I am not scheduling a console command but the command which resides under `App/Commands` directory ? Thanks

Comment: Added the code snippet to question in the manner u @luceos suggested `using closure` .
Unsure how to check the schedular working or not in xampp (localhost windows)